# nodejs Sharp resized images become 0 bytes

Tags: node.js, image-processing, sharp

I'm using sharp within a nodejs app to resize images. Sometimes when people upload images, it will always successfully save the main image, but then the resized images are sometimes saved as 0 bytes.

```
           await temp.mv(path.resolve(folderName + name + '.' + extension))
                .then((results) => {
                    
                    sharp(folderName + name + '.' + extension)
                        .resize(150, 110, {
                            fit: 'cover'
                        })
                        .toFile(folderName + name + '-150x110' + '.' + extension, function(err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        })

                    sharp(folderName + name + '.' + extension)
                        .resize(350, 350, {
                            fit: 'cover'
                        })
                        .toFile(folderName + name + '-350x350' + '.' + extension, function(err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        })

                    sharp(folderName + name + '.' + extension)
                        .resize(385, 258, {
                            fit: 'cover'
                        })
                        .toFile(folderName + name + '-385x258' + '.' + extension, function(err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        })


                })
```

Has anyone had problems with sharp in the past? I've never had any problems until recently, and the file sizes for the images aren't massive. I was wondering if it was a buffer problem, but I don't know why the images would be sometimes 0 bytes, it seems completely random. I can upload an image and get 5 quality resized images back, but sometimes you upload an image and get a couple that are 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having a problem with code that does asynchronous processing.

Also, `await`, `callback`, and `catch/then` are all mixed up in the code. I believe simply `await` can solve the your problem.

Check this:

```
try {
  const results = await temp.mv(path.resolve(folderName + name + '.' + extension));
  await sharp(folderName + name + '.' + extension)
    .resize(150, 110, {
      fit: 'cover'
    })
    .toFile(folderName + name + '-150x110' + '.' + extension);

  await sharp(folderName + name + '.' + extension);
    .resize(350, 350, {
      fit: 'cover'
    })
    .toFile(folderName + name + '-350x350' + '.' + extension);

  await sharp(folderName + name + '.' + extension)
    .resize(385, 258, {
      fit: 'cover'
    })
    .toFile(folderName + name + '-385x258' + '.' + extension);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```